# Compressing audio stream data in python and decompressing in java

Tags: java, android, python, audio, compression

I successfully stream audio over TCP from python running on raspberry pi to an android application and I am trying to use compression but it's only working with strings and not working with data from audio stream (only noise is heard) 
here is my python code:

```
    while True:
      data = stream.read(CHUNKS)
      outData = StringIO()
      d = GzipFile( mode="w", fileobj = outData)
      d.write(data)
      d.close()
      conn.send((outData.getvalue()))
```

and my android code:

```
    speaker = newAudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    speaker.play();
    DataInputStream ds = new DataInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
    GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(ds);
    while (true) {
    gzip.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    speaker.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);}
```

Does anybody have an idea why this is not working? Also, are there alternative ways to achieve what I'm trying to?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might not be in GZIP at all:

`AudioTrack` used only for uncompressed audio as mentioned here:

[`It allows streaming of PCM audio buffers to the audio sink`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html)

You might give the `MediaPlayer` a try, as an example:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.setDataSource("http://...");
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

Yet this might not be what you need as you are trying to use [`Socket`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html)

In this case you might use Temporary file as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272664/create-mediaplayer-with-inputstream-in-android)

OR use a [Local HTTP server to stream an `InputStream` to `MediaPlayer` on Android](https://gist.github.com/abeluck/6243306)

Hope this can help, best of luck :)